# I cant add AND to my script, to call another WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show only news types from certain categories.
The category names are **News**, and **Website Updates**

The problem with this, is that i can't add "AND category =..." after the first WHERE.
I have many more categories, and this is why I want to include only these two as the main news.

if you're wondering,
escape() is mysql_escapes function

Anyone to help? much appreciated.

```
<?
$sql_posts = query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category = '" . escape("News") . "' ORDER BY date DESC");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql_posts) == "0") { echo "No posts yet"; }
else
{
    while($qry_posts = mysql_fetch_array($sql_posts))
    {
        $todaysdate = $date;
        if($qry_posts['date'] == $todaysdate) {
            echo "<div style=\"text-align:right;\"><img src=\"images/addedtodayarrowdown.png\">&nbsp;<b style=\"color: #ffb400;\">ADDED TODAY</b></div>";
            $postdate = str_replace('/', '-', $qry_posts['date']);
            $postdate = date('F jS, Y', strtotime($postdate));
            echo '<a href="?module=posts&id=' . $qry_posts['id'] . '" style="background:url(images/h2_news_today.jpg) no-repeat;"><span style="float:right;">' . $postdate . '</span>' . $qry_posts['title'] . "</a>";
        }
        else
        {
            $postdate = str_replace('/', '-', $qry_posts['date']);
            $postdate = date('F jS, Y', strtotime($postdate));

            $filetitle = substr($file, 10);
            echo '<a href="?module=posts&id=' . $qry_posts['id'] . '"><span style="float:right;">' . $postdate . '</span>' . $qry_posts['title'] . "</a>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are searching for the [`OR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) operator:

```
$sql_posts = query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category = '" . escape("News") . "' OR category ='" . escape("Website Updates") . "' ORDER BY date DESC");
```

Comments:

- Don't use the deprecated MySQL extension. Switch to [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/book.mysqli.php) (with prepared statements) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)!
- You don't actually need to escape "News" or "Website Updates" since they do not come from an external source.
- Use [here docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for better formatting:

  ```
  $sql = <<< END
  SELECT *
  FROM posts
  WHERE category = 'News'
     OR category = 'Website Updates'
  ORDER BY date DESC
  END;

  $sql_posts = query($sql);
  ```
- As a last point, you can also use the [`IN(...)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) syntax as Chris Rasco (+1) pointed out in his post:

  ```
  $sql = <<< END
  SELECT *
  FROM posts
  WHERE category IN ('News', 'Website Updates')
  ORDER BY date DESC
  END;

  $sql_posts = query($sql);
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$sql_posts = query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category IN ('" . escape("News") . "', '" . escape("Website") . "', '" . escape("Updates") . "') ORDER BY date DESC");
```

Keep in mind that your category can't be "News" AND "Website" so an "AND" condition is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You want an OR statement not an AND one.

```
$sql_posts = query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category = '" . escape("News") 
                . "' OR category = '"
                . escape("Other thing")
                . "' ORDER BY date DESC");
```